# Using models clean method for fields validation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to check the model field for a list of available items before I save them to the database.

models.py

```
class Vendors(models.Model):
    COUNTRY_CHOICES = tuple(countries)
    ...
    country = models.CharField(max_length=45, choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES)
    ...
```

class for saving models

```
class CsvToDatabase(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = request.data
        for key, vendor in data.items():
            Vendors(
                ...,
                country=vendor['Country'],
                ...,

            ).save()

        return Response({'received data': request.data,
                         'message': 'Vendors from vendors_list were successfully added to the database'})
```

For validation Im added **clean** method to models

```
def clean(self):
    if self.country not in [x[1] for x in countries]:
        raise ValidationError(detail="Country name does not match to the country list ")
```

But it doesnt work

Next step I added the same code to method **save**

```
def save(self):
    if self.country not in [x[1] for x in countries]:
        raise ValidationError(detail="Country name does not match to the country list ")
```

And it works, but  I read that using validation in the save method is not correct. And the correct method for use - **clean**, why in my case it does not work?

Comment: The correct way is indeed to use `clean()`, however the `clean()` method on a model isn't called automatically. It gets called when you clean a `ModelForm` for the model (by checking `form.is_valid()`) or when you validate a `ModelSerializer`. You can also just call it yourself. Create the `Vendors` object, call `full_clean()` first (and catch the ValidationError) and only after that call `save()`. Note: if you call `full_clean()`, the model will already validate that the country is set correctly, you don't need to add that in `clean()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [model validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) for a full explanation of how validating models works.

In short: To validate an object, you need to call `full_clean()` on the object. This does not happen automatically! It happens when:

- You use a `ModelForm` and call `is_valid()` on the form
- You use a `ModelSerializer` in DRF and call `is_valid()` on the serializer
- You call `full_clean()` explicitly

In your case, just create the object, call `full_clean()` and then `save()`. Note you don't even have to add your own check (`clean()` method) because the check for valid choices is automatically performed by Django during `clean_fields()` when `choices` is set on a field:

```
v = Vendors(country=vendor['country'], ...)
try:
    v.full_clean()
except ValidationError as e:
    # do something e.g. return error response
v.save()
return Response(...)
```

Comment: Great, it works and it's very useful information for me. One more thing for me - how to catch the exceptions ? Now I have an exception from the clean model method, and I would like to use an exception from the POST class method. Im created a new question for this. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Notice: `ModelSerializer.is_valid` doesn't actually call `Model.full_clean`